# Target all classes following (with sass)

Tags: css, sass

I wanna know how can I target the following classes

```
<div class="Table-divider__meta">
<div class="Table-divider__data">
```

I have this

```
.Table {

&-divider*{
    @include breakpoint($md) {
      @include display(flex);
      @include flex-flow(row wrap);
      @include flex-grow(1);
      @include flex-basis(0);
    }
}
```

But isnt working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do wild card matching in class selectors.

The clean approach would be to use multiple classes:

```
<div class="Table divider meta">
<div class="Table divider data">
```

and

```
.Table.divider {

}
```

Otherwise you can investigate [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), which do allow for a degree of pattern matching.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was trying not to "over code" my css file.